# forward log messages from syslog to custom log in Linux server

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j, ubuntu-server

I'm going to send my logs from syslog to a custom log in ubuntu server, you guys know what should I do ? how can I config my rsyslog.conf? is there any direct way to send my logs from spring boot app to a custom log not syslog server?

Comment: I don't see what seems to be the problem? The [`FileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender) is very well documented. Is this Ubuntu server on a different server than the source of the log messages?

Comment: oh you mean I can use file appender instead of fetching them from my log files from server, right?

Comment: Yes, you can use a `FileAppender` or `RollingFileAppender` to write log messages to a file on the local machine (assuming you are using Log4j 2). Since you are using Spring Boot you can also set a value to the Spring property `logging.file.path`, which works independently of the actual logging system (cf. [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.file-output)).

Comment: Pouria- Please check (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)how to ask a good question. Your question is currently missing too much information to be able to help you

Comment: thanks but the page does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot uses Logback by default. Logback contains a syslog appender, see here: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender:

```xml
<configuration>

  <appender name="SYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
    <syslogHost>remote_home</syslogHost>
    <facility>AUTH</facility>
    <suffixPattern>[%thread] %logger %msg</suffixPattern>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

To get fine-grained control over Spring Boot logging, see here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.logging.custom-log-configuration

You could add the snippet above in the `logback-spring.xml`. Citing from the documentation:

> When possible, we recommend that you use the -spring variants for your logging configuration (for example, logback-spring.xml rather than logback.xml). If you use standard configuration locations, Spring cannot completely control log initialization.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I could connect to syslog and entered my logs to it but I want to send my logs to my custom logs in ubuntu server. is there any direct way for it? I read somewhere it's name is log rotation but I'm not sure.